# Connect to remote computer with another user account

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, remote-login

I connected to a computer in our company LAN with an account (for example, user1). A login dialog appeared and asked me its username and password. Then, I checked a check box to remember the password. Though, I will log into this system using this user by default.
Now, I need to log into that system again. But this time, with another account. But no login dialog box appears for me.
What should I do ?

Comment: Any particular OS and protocol?

Comment: What do you mean by "connect"? Did you open it in the windows file explorer via "browse network"?

Comment: OS is Windows7. Just I entered its IP like `\\192.168.1.150` in the run in start menu ...

Comment: I've turned a computer on.  I tried to do something but it didn't work.  It once worked.  How can I make it work again?

Comment: @artistoex If you are also having a issue I recommend you open your own question. You will need to provide much more details in your question as right now your statement is extremely generic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to control panel -> credential manager, and remove the stored credentials from there.
If it's not shown there.

on a command prompt shell:

1. run command "net use"
   this will show list of network connections stored.
2. from output of last command, run:
   `net use /delete \\{network_machine_connection}`
3. try accessing machine after that.

Comment: I fixed some of your text formatting, you can roll it back if you don't want it.